# Can autorun's reactive computation be dependent on part of a collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

I'd like to create a template in Meteor that has a Tracker.autorun which exclusively runs when part of a document changes --- but not when other parts of the document change.
So here is sample code using a minimongo collection and template.autorun

**parent.html**

```
{{#each items}}
  {{> child}}
{{/each}}
```

**child.html**

```
<div>{{title}}</div>
<p>{{description}}</p>
```

**Minimongo Collection**

```
LocalProject.findOne() output:
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "hi",
        "description": "test"
      },
      {
        "title": "hi 2",
        "description": "test 2"
      },
    ],
    "otherstuff:{//etc}
```

**child.js**

```
Template.child.onRendered(function(){
    this.autorun(function() {
        var data = Template.currentData();
        doSomething(data.title,data.description)
    });
});
```

**addnewitem.js**

```
LocalProject.update(currentEditingProjectID,{ $push: { 'items': newItem }},function(error,result){
    if(error){console.log(error)}
});
```

The problem is, whenever I run addnewitem.js, all of my Template.child autoruns execute even though their reactive data source (Template.currentData()) has not changed unless it was the specific item I updated. Similarly if I want to update an existing item, not just add a new one to the array, all of the autoruns for each item get executed.

So is there a way, using this model, to create a dependency for autorun that is reactively granular to specific portions of a document?

Comment: In order to help you, I need to know what doSomething() does.

Comment: @steph643 doSomething() is used to update a GSAP timeline/animation. I'm not sure how that ties in, but I appreciate any insight here. I'm still looking for a proper solution to boil down reactive dependencies to single portions of documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the way to go is by using an autorun. I would either set up individual reactive dependencies on each item, or use `observe`/`observeChange`.

### First idea

**parent.html:**

```
{{#each items}}
  {{> child}}
{{/each}}
```

**parent.js:**

```
Template.parent.helpers({
  // Returns only item ids
  items: function() { 
    return Items.find({}, { fields: { _id: 1 } });
  }
});
```

**child.html:**

```
{{#each items}}
  {{#with item=getItem}}
    <div>{{item.title}}</div>
    <p>{{item.description}}</p>
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

**child.js:**

```
Template.child.helpers({
  getItem: function() {
    // Get the item and set up a reactive dependency on this particular item
    var item = Items.find(this._id);

    // After item has been displayed, do something with the dom
    Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
      doSomething(item.title, item.description);
    });

    return item;
  }
});
```

### Second idea

**parent.html:**

```
{{#each items}}
  {{> child}}
{{/each}}
```

**parent.js:**

```
function do(item) {
  Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
    doSomething(item.title, item.description);
  });
}

Template.parent.onCreated({
  this.items = Items.find({});
  this.handle = this.items.observe({
    added:   function(item)             { do(item); },
    changed: function(oldItem, newItem) { do(newItem); },
  });  
});

Template.parent.onDestroyed({
  this.handle.stop();
});

Template.parent.helpers({
  items: function() { 
    return Template.instance().items;
  }
});
```

**child.html:**

```
{{#each items}}
  <div>{{title}}</div>
  <p>{{description}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I essentially broke down and put all my items in to a separate collection where each item was an individual document and refactored from there. I haven't tried your second idea but I appreciate both approaches and the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool just for this - [3stack:embox-value](https://atmospherejs.com/3stack/embox-value) provides reactive isolation, and value caching.

Using your example, you could isolate changes to title/description like so:

first up, add the packages

```
meteor add 3stack:embox-value
meteor add ejson
```

Then, update your code:

```
Template.child.onRendered(function(){
     // creates a reactive data source, that only triggers "changes"
     // when the output of the function changes.
     var isolatedData = this.emboxValue(function(){
        var data = Template.currentData();
        return {title: data.title, description: data.description}
    }, {equals: EJSON.equals})

    this.autorun(function() {
         // This autorun will only execute when title or description changes.
        var data = isolatedData()
        doSomething(data.title,data.description)
    });
});
```